# Using log in inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I saw several specific questions on using logarithm on an inequality. In this question I want a general answer. This idea came from reading [Paradoxes and Sophisms in Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857812). Relevant to this topic are questions 11,12 and 13 of chapter 3 in the book. For the purpose of the question logarithm is assumed to be taken on real number. Any suggestion to define the question is welcome as I am not myself sure what other possibilities are there other than those mentioned in the questions above.

To illustrate the problem here is a suggestion:

$$ 3 \gt 2 $$
$$ => \log_x 3  > \log_x 2 $$

The question is which values of $x$ are applicable here. Also how the values of $x$ change when we change the inequality in any way like replacing one side with a function or changing values for other range like between $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Well. Note if 0 <a <1 then a^n < a.  If a >1 than a^n > a and if a = 1 a^x equal 1.  You ought to be able to reach you answer from that.

Comment: @fleablood thanks. I anly gave the above example as a suggestion. I want to know about other variations of the question and how answer changes with that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Making the problem more general, under which condition does hold the inequality $$ A=\log_x(a)  - \log_x(b) >0$$ Converting to natural logarithms, this write $$\frac{\log (a)}{\log (x)}-\frac{\log (b)}{\log (x)}=\frac{\log(\frac a b)}{\log(x)}$$ which has the same sign as $${\log(\frac a b)}\,{\log(x)}$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.